# .htaccess Deny All But POST Not Working With Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c, .htaccess, http, post

I have been looking around for ways to deny all HTTP methods but POST. Yes i realize this might not prevent much but i would like to make it work. I came across a way to deny all but post using the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST
RewriteRule ^.*$ /home/user/public_html/folder/bad_request.php
```

Now in my iphone app i have the following code which POST's data to the website:

```
NSString *post_length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[post_data length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://folder.domain.com/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:post_length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:post_data];
```

When i run this code with my current .htaccess as shown above i get the bad_request page as if i wasnt POSTing data but if i change the .htaccess rule to !^GET i can visit it in the browser and gain access but when i post with the iPhone code i get denied...so that works backwards. Does anyone have an idea why it wont work?

Comment: Your description doesn't follow: 'if i change the .htaccess rule to !^GET i can visit it in the browser and gain access but when i post with the iPhone code i get denied...so that works backwards' - that sounds right if you have !^GET?

Comment: What about POST requests from a desktop system?

Comment: Ill try that now but the POST request is coming from an iPhone simulator on my Mac and I also tried cURL.

Comment: @Robbie If I put !^GET I can access it through a browser but not the iPhone. When I put !^POST I naturally can't access it through the browser but the iPhone should be able to but it doesn't, on GET one out of the two attempts works but on POST none of the attempts work. Sorry if I worded that incorrectly.

Comment: That makes sense - just wasn't sure. I presume it works without the .htaccess? Going to add some debug in the answer box (handles code better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after trying with no success i finally decided to incorporate a portion of your suggested .htaccess code along with some .php. I have the .htaccess file get the request method and send it to the index.php, the index.php file then says if its == 'POST' do something else do something else and it works.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?request=%{REQUEST_METHOD} [L,QSA]
```

index.php

```
if ($_GET['request'] == 'POST') {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Comment - not answer, but need to add code)

Assuming the POST message is getting through from the iPhone (which you can verify be removing the filter in .htaccess) then you probably need to find out what type of request you are getting

To do this:

1) Create a PHP file "t.php" with the following code:

```
<?php

echo 'htaccess sees: **' . htmlentities($_GET['m']) . '**<br>';
echo 'apache sees: **' . htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) . '**';

?>
```

2) Create an .htaccess with the following:

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
# Add Options SymLinks if you need it
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) t.php?m=%{REQUEST_METHOD} [L,QSA]
```

Then run and note the results. All requests to the server will go to t.php, and it'll show you what is being handles by .htaccess and what is being passes to PHP as the server method. The asteriscs are to ensure there are no spaces. Double check these are both "**POST**". You'll need to trap the output in your iPhone debugger, or get PHP to pump to a log file.

Comment: Ok so i tested this out and here are my results. From the iPhone i get: 2012-11-23 06:57:10.537 Start Up[8687:c07] htaccess sees: **POST**<br>apache sees: **POST**

From the web browser i get: htaccess sees: **GET**
apache sees: **GET**

So it seems to be receiving the correct methods

Comment: So no reason why it shouldn't work. Put your htaccess back. Is there anything else in your htaccess? Or is it all posted above. And also can you confirm it works if the restriction is not there

Comment: Yes thats the only thing in my htaccess, and yes it works when its blank, this is very confusing.

Comment: Ok, next trick. Do a post from a php/html  form. Does that get blocked, as the post from the iPhone does? Or can that get through?

Comment: Ok so i tried posting from an .html webpage and it works perfectly. I made sure it was a post and i also tested blocking post and i was displayed the bad_request page. So now I'm wondering why any other post isn't working.

Comment: ok, add [PT] to the end if the rewrite rule. See if that helps.

Comment: No luck either. I even tried posting using curl from another php file.

Comment: Sorry - totally out of ideas! Nothing looks wrong, apache reports the right info. The only final thing I can suggest is rewrite logging: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog set level to 9 and see what gets reported. Sorry I can't help more.